# ItemsControl with DataTriggers

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

Can someone provide a simple example how could you use DataTriggers on an ItemsControl?

For example if i say something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="2">
       <Setter TargetName="DocHost" Property="UniformGrid.Rows" Value="2"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ItemsControl.Triggers>
```

It gives me an error saying that ItemsControl expects an event trigger. Sadly i must use DataTriggers inside and ItemsControl. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a `DataTrigger` in a `TriggerCollection`... yes, yes, I know... it's madness. However, you *can* put one in the `TriggerCollection` of a `Style`:

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="2">
                <Setter TargetName="DocHost" Property="UniformGrid.Rows" Value="2"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Style>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Sorry, I didn't see that `TargetName` in there. The answer is to move this `DataTrigger` into the `UnifrmGrid.Style` instead and remove the `TargetName` property, but then you *might* have some trouble `Binding` to the `Items` property... let me know if you have any more problems.

Comment: True, but now i cannot set a target name inside a style setter :(

Comment: You are most welcome. This is an issue that will come up again and again... if you can remember to just move the `DataTrigger` to the control that contains the property used in it, you'll save yourself a lot of time.