# Style resource depending on string variable

Tags: .net, wpf

I need the styling of an item in an itemcontrol to depend on a string variable of the item. So If the string is ’A’ that item should have style 1 If its ’B’ it should have style 2 and so on.

I have been looking around but can't really find a straight forward way of doing this so I have no code to show at the moment. I think maybe I don’t know the name of concepts I should search for.

So the question is: Is there a straight forward typical way of doing this in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

DataTriggers should do it. Not ItemsControl, but should be similar

UPDATE: [ItemsControl with DataTriggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517512/itemscontrol-with-datatriggers)

```
<ListBox ....> 
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Gender}" Value="Male">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Gender}" Value="Female">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        YourClass dataObj = item as YourClass;
        if (dataObj != null)
        {
            switch (dataObj.TheStringProperty)
            {
                case "A":
                    return TemplateA;
                case "B":
                    return TemplateA;
            }
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="a">
            <TextBlock>I am an A...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="b">
            <TextBlock>I am a B...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:TemplateSelector TemplateA="{StaticResource a}" TemplateB="{StaticResource b}" />
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```